# Android App doesn't give me all options

Tags: discussion, android

Using the android app, I can't close, edit, or even use mod privileges at all.  Is that done for a reason, or is it a bug?

Comment: I can close and edit. Do you see no buttons or do you get errors?

Comment: @Seth I see no buttons.

Comment: Tap "asked x mins ago".

Comment: cool, that did it :)

Comment: General Android usage: look for three dots/bars (ellipsis) for more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a normal user running the normal app atleast, you should be able to tap the 'Asked/Edited' button and edit/flag/close things

[image]

There also seems to be an option to open the page in a internet browser so you can use options that aren't available in the app.

[image]

Comment: Note that they are in the process of changing this to be more obvious.